# Is it possible to set the state of a radioButton into IsChecked = false upon second click?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have 4 radio buttons in one group.
Upon clicking the radio button the state will be changed into `IsChecked = true`.
I want to change the state of the radio button to `IsChecked = false` when I clicked a checked radio button.
Is this possible in XAML?

Comment: maybe something like if(Ischecked==true) Ischecked=false;else Ischecked=true;

Comment: Are the Radiobuttons databound?

Comment: no the radioButtons are not data bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the checked status of four radio buttons in the group. Every time, any of the radio button is clicked you need to update the status to most recent. Following is the code that you can try.

XAML Code....

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <RadioButton GroupName="LotOfFour" Tag="0" Click="RadioButton_Click" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Unchecked="RadioButton_Unchecked"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="LotOfFour" Tag="1" Click="RadioButton_Click" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Unchecked="RadioButton_Unchecked"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="LotOfFour" Tag="2" Click="RadioButton_Click" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Unchecked="RadioButton_Unchecked"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="LotOfFour" Tag="3" Click="RadioButton_Click" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Unchecked="RadioButton_Unchecked"/>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind...

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private Boolean[] _ischecked; 
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _ischecked = new Boolean[] { false, false, false, false };
    }

    private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Checked");
    }

    private void RadioButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");
    }

    private void RadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rbSource = sender as RadioButton;
        if ((rbSource != null) && (rbSource.IsChecked == true))
        {
            try
            {
                Int32 index = Int32.Parse(rbSource.Tag.ToString());
                Boolean isSourceChecked = _ischecked[index];
                // Now reset all to false, source will be set accordingly in ifelse block.
                _ischecked[0] = false;
                _ischecked[1] = false;
                _ischecked[2] = false;
                _ischecked[3] = false;
                if (isSourceChecked == true)
                {
                    _ischecked[index] = false;
                    rbSource.IsChecked = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    _ischecked[index] = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this in the Checked and Unchecked events of the radiobutton

```
    public bool Ischecked { get; set; }
    private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ischecked = true;
    }

    private void RadioButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ischecked = false;
    }
```